# How do I build an array out of a JSON object with starter keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Code

```
var q = JSON.parse('[{"15": {"bUrl": "https://example.com/r2359","name": "Ninpo","url": null,"desc": null,"series": [{"title": "Nana","id": "6308","authors": ["Author1"]}]}}, {"390": {"bUrl": "https://example.com/r2667","name": "Sanpo","url": null,"desc": null,"series": [{"title": "Baba","id": "6498","authors": ["Author2"]}]}}]');

var yy = [];
for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    yy.push(q[i]);
}
console.log(yy);
```

I'm trying to access the strings "15" and "390", but looping over them is just giving me the entire object for each group. How do I pull just the number strings, so that I can build an array with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` on the objects to get the keys as an array, and use a combination of `Array#reduce` and `Array#concat` to flat map the keys into a single array.

```js
var q = JSON.parse('[{"15": {"bUrl": "https://example.com/r2359","name": "Ninpo","url": null,"desc": null,"series": [{"title": "Nana","id": "6308","authors": ["Author1"]}]}}, {"390": {"bUrl": "https://example.com/r2667","name": "Sanpo","url": null,"desc": null,"series": [{"title": "Baba","id": "6498","authors": ["Author2"]}]}}]');

console.log(
  Object.keys(q[0])
)

console.log(
  q.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(Object.keys(x)), [])
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```